# copy files in linux which are existing at destination folder from the given list

Tags: linux, copy

How to copy files in Linux such that it should copy all files or if all files are not present than it should copy the existing files

Currently I am doing as below :

```
cp {file1,file2} /origin /destination
```

But the above command gives error if any of the one file is not present. I want to tell `cp` that copy any file which is present or if both then copy both.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `find` utility and its wealth of features! Read its manual: `man find`

```
find {file1,file2} -exec cp {} destination/ \;
```